# ReactJS Hooks: self calling Timeout not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In a [ReactJS Functional Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#hooks-and-function-components) using [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) I'd like to call a function that will:

1. Increment a property in the Component's State
2. Set a `Timeout` to call itself again in a constant amount of time

Here's a simplified example of that Component:

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [counterTimeout, setCounterTimeout] = useState(null);
  const updateCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    console.log(count);
    setCounterTimeout(window.setTimeout(updateCount, 500));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    updateCount();
    return window.clearTimeout(counterTimeout);
  }, []);
  return null;
};
```

What I'm struggling with is **why that State property isn't updated ?**

Also, *bonus points* if you can tell me how to clear that `Timeout` on Component unmount (pretty sure it won't really work like that);

Thanks ❤️

Comment: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const updateCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(updateCount, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [count]);
  return <span>{count}</span>;
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-520gr

With a setTimeout.

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const updateCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(updateCount, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, [count]);
  return <span>{count}</span>;
};
```

Comment: It does, thanks! Could you please update it to use a Timeout instead of an Interval though? My Component example is *simplified* to only highlight the technical concepts that I'm trying to use and I'm not sure an Interval will fit (but I'll think about it). Also, could you please explain *why it works*? I like when things aren't as magical as a copy paste on SO 

Comment: Good point, a setTimeout will function just like a setInterval here as useEffect will be continuously recalled.. As to why it works, on the mount it creates the interval which will run your updateCount function every second. You'll notice I've added count to the dependency array of UseEffect, without that setInterval would have only a reference to the value of count from when it was initially created. So it'll be adding 1 to 0 every time and that's all you'll ever see. Now when count is useEffect.

Comment: This is incorrect as it will restart the timer each time count changes, even if it is changed directly with setCount

Comment: Is that not exactly what he wants?

Answer (score -1):

I've fixed your code and will try to explain, which is hopefully correct. I've also added an alternative using `setInterval` instead of retriggering a `setTimeout`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-ives-502hz

The problem is the rerendering of the component. Everytime a property or state object is changed, the component is rerendered so all object inside are created again. This is also true for `updateCount`. But the method inside of `useEffect` will only be recreated when one of the listening parameters are changing. In your case the array is empty, so this will only run once at mounting of a `Counter` component. So the reference to `updateCount` is not the same as inside the component after rerendering because of `setCount`.

To bypass this problem `useRef` comes to the rescue. With this a "static" variable can be created. So this will not be recreated when the component is rerendered. So we can keep our reference to the timer handler here and call `clearTimeout`. The next thing is the access of `count`.

I'm not sure if this explanation is correct: `setCount` will not update the current `count` but will create a new object. So after calling `setCount` the current `count` has still the same old value. For this `setCount` can be called in a different way by providing a function which will internally be called with the current value of `count`. To be able to output the `console.log` just add another `useEffect` which will be called everytime `count` changes by listening to `count`.

```js
const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const counterTimeout = useRef(null);

  const updateCount = () => {
    setCount(count => count + 1);
    counterTimeout.current = window.setTimeout(updateCount, 500);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("count", count);
  }, [count]);

  useEffect(() => {
    updateCount();
    return () => {
      window.clearTimeout(counterTimeout.current);
    };
  }, []);
  return null;
};
```

For completion here is my alternative with the same approach but using `setInterval`. Because of this the interval handling is only inside the `useEffect` so no reference is needed. It also has a small optimisation by using `useCallback` for `updateCount`.

```js
const CounterInterval = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const updateCount = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(count => count + 1);
  }, [setCount]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("interval count", count);
  }, [count]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const counterTimeout = window.setInterval(updateCount, 500);
    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(counterTimeout);
    };
  }, []);
  return null;
};
```